# Password Manager for Ubuntu Phone

Tags: phone, keepass

I just bought a Meizu Ubuntu Phone and so far I'm quite happy. To get rid of my Android phone I need a password manager like keepassx. Mkpasswd can create new passwords but I also need to store existing passwords.
Any suggestions for an app?

Cheers
Bernhard

Comment: Password gorilla

Answer (score 0):

password-shroud - 
its new and alpha but you could try: 
https://uappexplorer.com/app/password-shroud.rene-so36